# Search for a date within a Date range in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, excel-formula, cell

I'm looking for a way to search for a cell within range of cells in a table using excel, so i need to look for Date-Time within a Range in table that has large amount of rows,

These pics attached show it all; the first pic shows what is the current scenario; I'm using the IF statement to know if the Date was found/Contained/included in range and If it was found then put "1" other than this put "0"
I have used this If statement before: 
`=IF(AND(AC5>=AE5,AC5<=AF5),"1","0")`

But the thing is its comparing each Row by Row, not Cell by Row, That is unwanted, 
The thing is i want to compare each cell by all of the ranges in the table and upon this it puts "1" or "0".

Please find the attached screenshots to clarify the question :
[Current Scenario Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9nJT.jpg)
[My Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKr8z.jpg)

Any Solutions please?

Comment: try this link-> http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/956-excel-date-falls-between-two-dates.html

Comment: Recommendations? Hard to do. Add a screenshot where you mock up the **expected result**. Row by row is easy, as you have done with your formula. It is not clear what you want to see as the final output.

Comment: Do you need to know where the matching row is in XYZ, or just that it has a matching row somewhere?

Comment: Actually i don't know where is the matching ones, the rows are above 17,000 its large amount of data, that's why the pivot table is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with `COUNTIFS` function? In the example [attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvR2l.jpg), I have cell A & B for dateranges. E has Dates. I used to `COUNTIFS` in column `F1 = COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&E1,B:B,">="&E1)` to identify whether dates in E within range A & B. If countifs return 1 or more, then it means data in E are within range.

Comment: Yes i have tried the If statement you wrote (countIfs) but its still comparing  each row by row, i mean like its comparing : E1 with A1-B1,    and E2 with A2-B2, and E3 with A3-B3.                                                                      But the thing is i want to compare each Cell of E column with Each row in A & B, like : E5 with A1-B1, and E3 with A6-B6... and so on

Comment: can you share your COUNTIFS statement used? are you giving same as mine? you should give range correctly. Eg: In mine, i gave as A:A & B:B.

Comment: also refer my attachment in the answer. It compares 5th row time with 2nd row correctly.

Comment: Yes , hopefully it will work, i tried yours now, but at first i was trying this one:  =COUNTIFS(AC5:AC26, ">=AE5", AC5:AC26, "<=AO5")..... Thank you